# Get number of rows updated with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

How to get how many rows updated with PreparedStatement?

`.getUpdateCount()` returns 0.

For `executeUpdate` got error:
***error occurred during batching: batch must be either executed or cleared***

my code:

```
updTrans = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement("update...");
updTrans.setInt(1, Integer.valueOf(transaksjonstatusid));
...
updTrans.addBatch();
upd = updTrans.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: On your last edit you added: updTrans.addBatch(); then upd = updTrans.executeUpdate() and get an error, but as BalusC mentionned, you should be using int [] updateCounts = stmt.executeBatch(); if you're using .addBatch();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using [`PreparedStatement#executeBatch()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) when using batches.

```
...
updTrans.addBatch();
upd = updTrans.executeBatch();
```

It returns an `int[]` containing update counts of each batch.

Comment: The actual return value *may* depend on the JDBC implementation used (more precisely, the JDBC driver used). If you consider it wrong as opposed to the JDBC API documentation (or the JDBC driver specific documentation), then consider posting an issue report at the JDBC driver vendor/maintainer. I can't go in detail since it's unknown which one you're using.

Comment: In general >= 0 returns are rows affected and < 0 returns are error codes.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to use:

```
int n = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Here you can find some explanations on how to use a [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: does executeUpdate() do commit? because i needn't commit oh that phase, i should commit later,as batch update

Comment: if executeUpdate() is executed in a transaction then no, it does not commit the transaction

Comment: The commit can be set up through the Connection object, not the Statement. You can use conn.setAutoCommit(false); execute your preparedStatement, then use conn.commit(); and set back the autocommit to true if needed.

Comment: @sergionni `executeUpdate()` doesn't commit unless auto-commit is `true`, I believe. If you want to do a batch update, though, you should be using `addBatch()` and `executeBatch()`. `executeBatch()` returns an `int[]` containing the update counts for each command in the batch.

Answer (score 5):

See The [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29)

> public int executeUpdate()
>                     throws SQLException
>
> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must
>   be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE
>   statement; or an SQL statement that
>   returns nothing, such as a DDL
>   statement.
>
> Returns:
>   either (1) the row count for INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements
>   or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing
>
> Throws:
>           SQLException - if a database access error occurs or the SQL
>   statement returns a ResultSet object

Answer (score 2):

`getUpdateCount` is meant to be used with the `execute(String sql)` method.  You are probably doing this:

```
String sql = "UPDATE some_table SET somecolumn = ? WHERE someId = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepare(sql);
ps.setString(1, val);
ps.setInt(2, id);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

In that case you should simply do

```
int rowsUpdated = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: It seems this returns the matching rows and not necessarily the rows affected with my setup (MySQL) - meaning rows that are already the same value as what it would be updated to are counted, even though they aren't actually updated. Running the update manually gives in MySQL Workbench: 0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0... while I get 1 from the Java executeUpdate().